# Is there any way to adjust the colour intensity during the playback of a video on my S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, video

I have tried many video players looking for a colour adjustment while playing a movie on my phone but I can't seem to find a setting such as this. Is the Android OS incapable of it?  Does the stock player have such a setting?  Any other way to do this?

OS: 4.1.1
S3